# UISlider dividing into range

Tags: ios, uikit, uislider

I want to do something like this. I have a `UISlider` its minimum value shuld be 0 and the maximum value should be 1000.And I want to divide this range into 10 parts. Like this.

0-----100----200----300----400

When user drag the slider from 0 it should directly stop at 100 position without stopping inbetween 0 and 100 when he drag from 100 it should directly jump into 200 should not stop inbetween 100 and 200 likewise.How can I do this? please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have to do this:**

slider.maximumValue = numberOfSteps;

slider.minimumValue = 0;

slider.continuous = NO;

**For setting**

NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)(slider_value + 0.5);

[slider setValue:index animated:NO];

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a small problem. When I drag it from the 0 its straight away going to the max level. doesnt go step by step. Just going to the last position directly

Comment: Then you are not setting index properly. Suppose you are going to 10 value from 0 index = (NSUInteger)(10+0.5)

Comment: slider.maximumValue = numberOfsteps not the maximum value of slider

Comment: Wah Reshmi, Wah, ki dile guru!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, just assign your slider range 0...10 and multiply changed value by 100

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need just like you the day before. With default UISlider, you can only increment either +1 or -1. Hence, if you are looking to have a increment in other values, you have to do it programmatically.

In your case, try this:

```
- (IBAction)[yourUISlider]:(id)sender {
      [[yourUISliderProperty] setValue:((int)(( [yourUISlider].value + 50) / 100) * 100) animated:NO];
      NSLog(@"%d", [yourUISlider].value );
  }
```

It worked for me, try it out :)

And for other increment values, check out the formula here:

```
((int)(( [yourSlider] + [yourIncrement/2] ) / [yourIncrement]) *[yourIncrement])
```

Then NSLog or output the value.